# how to use enum in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 tables as follows

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end


class Book < ApplicationRecord
end

class Status < ApplicationRecord
end
```

After looking online i saw i could use status in enum and get rid of Status model.

Status can be one `available, pending, damaged, missing, returned`

I looked at some articles online about `enum` but i am still not clear how to use it.

If i update book model like this,

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:available, :pending, :damaged, :missing, :returned]
end
```

That means i'll have to add `status` column in book table so am i inserting status column with those values (available, pending, damaged etc.)?

If yes, how is the use of having same values in model again?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the comment for `enum` in the source code? It's huge, at `activerecord-*/lib/active_record/enum.rb`...

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out?  Did either answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can make status an `integer` field on the Book model and then set up the enum like this

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  # Enumerator
  enum status: {available: 0, pending: 1, damaged: 2, missing: 3, returned: 4}
end
```

Comment: Thanks. so i'll have 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 values in database in status column?

Comment: yes but those text values are what is shown, so like if you put `<%= book.status %>` and the status is 0 it would output `available`.  And you would search for it based on the text to, so a query would be `where(:status == 'pending')` not `where(:status ==  1)`.  I would also recommend making sure to set a default value in the migration

Comment: so that means, from application side user should know those combinations (available: 0, pending: 1, damaged: 2, missing: 3, returned: 4) ?

Comment: From the front end you mean?  They would not interact with the numbers at all, just the text, so like selecting a value they would be selecting text in a dropdown or something,  a user would not need to know numbers at all.  Setting up the enum in the model sets that up.

Comment: yes from front end. so if say user selects available, what is the integer `0` used?

Comment: that integer is saved in the database and is represented in the front end by the value `available`, which is readable.  This allows you flexibility, lets say you needed to add `discontinued` to the list, you could just add to the enum `discontinued: 5` and then go on from there no need to update the database

Comment: in case `discontinued: 5` i'd have to insert `5` in database though right?

Comment: well the integer would just get saved, you can insert an number into that field, you do not have to set anything up ahead of time it is an integer field so you can save any number, so 5 would then get saved if you added that to the enum

Answer (score 0):

in database status must be declared int

and u can set and get book status like example:
book.status = 'available'
puts book.status --> it prints avialable but in database it gets written as int.

This is good explanation link how enums work
https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/